# Visual Studio Code can't find PHP function - maybe "require_once" syntax?

Tags: php, visual-studio-code

[Solution] The "Undefined function" message was actually coming from SonarLint. I added type hinting to the function, and SonarLint no longer complains.

---

I would like to switch to Visual Studio Code for PHP development.

All of my files start with `require_once` with this syntax

```
require_once(__DIR__ .  DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . '..' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . '..' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'common'  . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'api'  . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'RequireCommonStuff.php');
```

and debugging won't launch, presumably because VSC says that there are problems with the file to be debugged, along the lines of

> Undefined function 'DumpGetAndPostParametersIfDebugging'.

where that function is declared in one of my required files.

Strangely, there are no problems reported for the `require_once` statements, but I can think of no other explanation for the function not being found.

The code works just fine with PHPstorm, I am testing on `localhost` - any ideas as to what I am doing wrongly?

---

[Update] the error is happenig with every function which is declared in a required file. Here's what leads to the first example.

in `RequireCommonStuff.php`, I just have more `require_once`s :

```
require_once(__DIR__ . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'constants.php');
require_once(__DIR__ . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'third_party' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR .'ChromePhp.php');
require_once(__DIR__ . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'errorHandling.php');
require_once(__DIR__ . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'trace.php');
require_once(__DIR__ . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'parseAndValidateUrlGetParameters.php');
```

The last of those is causing the error I discuss (although all of them cause erros). It's contents are (note: no classes involved), header comment stripped

```
function ParseAndValidateUrlGetParameters($url, 
                                         $inputType, 
                                         $filter, 
                                         $debug, 
                                         $reportIndicent=true, 
                                         $allFieldsMandatory=true)
{
```

Comment: Does this help? https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/php

Comment: Alas, no. But, upvoted for a useful link :-)

Comment: No one else here uses VSC for PHP development?

Comment: Although I'm not suggesting to change your coding style, could you try temporarily switching to using the literal `require_once __DIR__ . '/constants.php'` format instead? Just in case VSC is having trouble parsing that out. It'd be weird, but it is good to rule out.

Comment: You, sir, are a genius!! Post that as an answer and I will accept it & award the bounty.

Answer (score 3):

not sure about it but you can install and test [PHP Intelephense](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=bmewburn.vscode-intelephense-client) instead of Intellisense. also check if php path is added in vscode "**php.validate.executablePath**".

Comment: Thanks for the tips. Yes, the path is set in the folder's JSON config. Switching InteliSense did not help :-(

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried using the `DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR` constant instead of `/`

```php
$slash = DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;
require_once(__DIR__ . "{$slash}..{$slash}..{$slash}common{$slash}api{$slash}RequireCommonStuff.php");
```

Comment: Sorry, but that didn't hel[P :-(  `require_once(__DIR__ .  DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . '..' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . '..' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'common'  . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'api'  . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'RequireCommonStuff.php');` still gives me the error. No problem with the `REQUIRE_ONCE`, but `Undefined function` for functions in that file

Comment: Can you share in the issue description the content of that file that you are requiring?

Comment: Done. I hope that it helps. This is all fine in PHPstorm, just not in VSC

Answer (score 2):

Just had the same problem and figured it out:
If you haven't done so you should use "Open Folder" from the "File" menu and navigate to where your PHP scripts are located. That way VSC apparently finds both scripts in its working directory and does not show the error anymore.

Side note: I am running VSC 1.55.2 and "PHP Intelephense", in case just opening the folder does not suffice for anybody.